# How to execute the commands in the Terminal using robot framework?

Tags: python, python-3.x, robotframework, robotframework-ide, robotframework-sshlibrary

I want to execute the below commands in the Terminal using Robot Framework step by step. Any advice on how to go about it?

```
 1. ssh -o ProxyCommand\='ssh -W %h:%p xx.xx.xx.xx' xx.xvb.xyz.wq
 2. password
 3. sudo su - pentaho
 4. cd pentaho/design-tools/data-integration/
 5. sh kitchen.sh -file\=/ebs/pentaho/history/etljob.kjb
```

Comment: Why do you want to use RF for this? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: That's a nice question. I am trying to automate end to end flow of my Database testing.
Step 1 - I add test data in UI
Step 2 - I run ETL jobs (Trying to achieve with above commands)
Step 3 - Run regression queries in Database (Using RF DB Libs)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try using [Process library](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Process.html#Run%20Process).

Keyword like [Run Process](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Process.html#Run%20Process) seems promising:

```
*** Settings ***
Library    Process     

*** Test Cases *** 
Python Tiny Program
    ${result} =     Run Process     python    -c    print('Hello, world!') 
    Log    ${result.stdout}
```

`${result}` will be an object, you can use various properties like `stdout`, `stderr`, `rc` and others. It's described in the official [doc](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Process.html#Result%20object).

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your advice. But I am not seeing the Result output of ${result.stdout}. It shows empty in my case.

Comment: Well, you can't interact with a shell in this way, so if you're expecting to get an interactive shell e.g. for login, this is not a good approach. And you'll see an output only for those commands that actually output something to the stdout etc.

Comment: So in order to execute the below commands, is this a correct way?

${Result}=    Run Process   python    -c      ssh -o ProxyCommand\='ssh -W %h:%p xx.xx.xx.xx' xx.xx.xx.xx
   Sleep    5s
   ${pwd1}=          Run Process       python  -c     123xxx567
   ${sudo}=             Run Process         python    -c   sudo su - pentaho

Comment: No, that's definitely not the right way. My answer was an example, you need to adapt it to your problem, I showed you the tools you might need for that. `Run Process` takes a shell command, I used python just as an example, you probably want to add the name of your script there. But as I said, you can't access an interactive shell like this, so typing your username and password is out of the question.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me! So how can I achieve above commands, by typing my username and password? Any advice?